# ERROR ITMS-90329 Your package contains with a name that contains leading or trailing whitespace

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

when i am submit my app to app store this msg error appear

ERROR ITMS-90329 Your package contains with a name that contains leading or trailing whitespace

I am trying to remove spaces from name , that not solved , Any Help resolve this error , thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove spaces from targets, delete DerivedData and make clean